# Error when i try do a batch_update gspread

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a problem with gspread, i'm trying do a worksheet.batch_update, but i receive this error mesage

> File "D:\ProyectoReal-Statement\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\worksheet.py", line 903, in 
> dict(vr, range=absolute_range_name(self.title, vr["range"])) for vr in data
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

My code is:

```
floor = [typeFloor #String, titleFloor #String, href #String, m2Floor #String, roomsFloor #Integer, priceFloor #Double]
listaFinal.append(floor)
rangeRows = 'A2' + ":F" + str(len(listaFinal))
worksheet.batch_update({
        'range': rangeRows,
        'values': listaFinal
                           })
```

Any idea how I can add a lot of information to my sheet or how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The argument `data` of `batch_update(data)` is required to be an array.
- In your script, when `len(listaFinal)` is `1`, the value is put from the cell "A1". From `rangeRows = 'A2' + ":F" + str(len(listaFinal))`, I believe that you wanted to put the values from "A2".

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
floor = [typeFloor #String, titleFloor #String, href #String, m2Floor #String, roomsFloor #Integer, priceFloor #Double]
listaFinal.append(floor)

rangeRows = 'A2' # Modified
worksheet.batch_update([{'range': rangeRows, 'values': listaFinal}], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED") # Modified
```

Or, I thought that in your script, the following modified script might be able to be used.

```py
floor = [typeFloor #String, titleFloor #String, href #String, m2Floor #String, roomsFloor #Integer, priceFloor #Double]
listaFinal.append(floor)

rangeRows = 'A2' # Modified
worksheet.update(rangeRows, listaFinal, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED") # Modified
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your value of `listaFinal` is 2 dimensional array. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update)
- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update)